# How to calculation this time (php session)

Tags: php, datetime, session

```
session_start();

$_SESSION['start1']= new DateTime('now');

$_SESSION['start2']= new DateTime('now +10 minute');

$_SESSION['time1'] = $_SESSION['start2']->diff($_SESSION['start1']);

$_SESSION['start3']= new DateTime('now +20 minute');

$_SESSION['start4']= new DateTime('now +30 minute');

$_SESSION['time2'] = $_SESSION['start3']->diff($_SESSION['start4']);

$_SESSION['alltime']=$_SESSION['time1']+$_SESSION['time1'];

echo $_SESSION['alltime']->format('%I minute %S second');
```

But not show time?

Comment: You should be getting all kinds of errors here. http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php

Comment: @Fred-ii- Well you get errors from the last 2 lines

Comment: Maybe you should tell us what you are actually trying to achieve

Comment: @RiggsFolly Oh, you meant these? `Notice: Object of class DateInterval could not be converted to int in /path/to/file.php on line 17 - 
Notice: Object of class DateInterval could not be converted to int in /path/to/file.php  on line 17 - 
Fatal error: Call to a member function format() on integer in /path/to/file.php on line 19` - well those are "my" line numbers anyway.

Comment: Why are you adding `time1` to `time1` anyway

Comment: @Fred-ii- **Yea them's the errors I get too**

Comment: @RiggsFolly GMTA ;-)

Comment: @Fred-ii- AFSD :( unfortunately, but were not two of those. Are we?

Comment: Basically you cannot add 2 DateInterval Objects together

Comment: **Maybe you should tell us what you are actually trying to achieve**

Answer (score 0):

You need to turn on error reporting:

```
<?php
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
?>
```

That will show you the problem.

Your code:

```
session_start();

$_SESSION['start1']= new DateTime('now');

$_SESSION['start2']= new DateTime('now +10 minute');

$_SESSION['time1'] = $_SESSION['start2']->diff($_SESSION['start1']);

$_SESSION['start3']= new DateTime('now +20 minute');

$_SESSION['start4']= new DateTime('now +30 minute');

$_SESSION['time2'] = $_SESSION['start3']->diff($_SESSION['start4']);

$_SESSION['alltime']=$_SESSION['time1']+$_SESSION['time1']; <----- $_SESSION[ 'alltime' ] is an integer

echo $_SESSION['alltime']->format('%I minute %S second');
```

Now there is more than likely a better way of completing this but I have given it a go.

```
$start1 = new DateTime('now');
$start2= new DateTime('now +10 minute');

$time1 = $start2->diff($start1);
$time1_min = $time1->format( '%I' );
$time1_sec = $time1->format( '%S' );
echo $time1->format( '%I minutes %S seconds' )."\n";
echo $time1_min."\n";

$start3= new DateTime('now +20 minute');
$start4= new DateTime('now +30 minute');

$time2 = $start3->diff($start4);
$time2_min = $time2->format( '%I' );
$time2_sec = $time2->format( '%S' );
echo $time2_min."\n";
echo $time2->format( '%I minutes %S seconds' )."\n";

$total_min = $time1_min + $time2_min;
$total_sec = $time1_sec + $time2_sec;

echo "Total is $total_min minutes and $total_sec seconds";
```

Basically it is finding the difference in minutes and seconds and adding them together, now you have to understand that if the seconds pass an 60 then it will not added to the minutes so you would need to work that out.

Also had to remove the session as eval.in didnt like it. https://eval.in/719160

Comment: Thanks, but i working now session. What is the correct code? $_SESSION['alltime']=$_SESSION['time1']+$_SESSION['time1'];

Comment: Yes mate, just add the session variable back into each of the variables above.